# submit date through list button and convert that in date/time field

Tags: php

i wish to enter the date time values by using drop down list ,
and after that i want  to convert that in date/time field,,
please sugest me th ecode,

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this:

**HTML:**

```
 <form method="post">
 ...........

 <select name="datetime">
   <option value="12 Jan 2009">12 Jan 2009</option>
   <!-- more options if you want ->
   ..................
   ..................
 </select>
```

**PHP:**

```
$datetime = $_POST['datetime'];
// convert string to date
$your_date = strtotime($datetime);
```

Now `$your_date` contains your date from dropdown you can manipulate any way you want :)